# How to connect Spring Boot Docker Container with Database Docker Container

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-network

I'm trying to connect my dockerized Spring Boot application with a PostgreSQL database in another Docker container, but I cannot do it.

Here are Dockerfile:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-jammy

WORKDIR /app

COPY .mvn/ .mvn
COPY mvnw pom.xml ./
RUN ./mvnw dependency:resolve

COPY src ./src

CMD ["./mvnw", "spring-boot:run"]
```

and application.yaml file:

```
server:
  port: 8080
  error:
    include-message: always

spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5332/customer
    username: username
    password: password
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: validate
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
        format_sql: true
    show-sql: true
  main:
    web-application-type: servlet
```

1. I built docker image with this command:
    `docker build --tag java-docker .`
2. Then I tried to connect to db docker through docker network with this command:

   `docker run --name java-docker --rm -p 8080:8080 --network demo_full_stack_postgres java-docker --spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/customer`

but got this error:

`docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "--spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/customer": stat --spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/customer: no such file or directory: unknown.`

What do I need to connect two containers together?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that

```
CMD ["./mvnw", "spring-boot:run"]
```

gets over-written by `--spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/customer` when you run the container. Docker can't find an executable called `--spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/customer`, so it fails.

The reason this happens is that anything after the image name on the `docker run` command replaces the `CMD` defined in the Dockerfile.

To fix this, you can change

```
CMD ["./mvnw", "spring-boot:run"]
```

to

```
ENTRYPOINT ["./mvnw", "spring-boot:run"]
```

With the same `docker run` command, the command that Docker will run will then be a concatenation of the entrypoint and the command you supply on the `docker run` command. I.e. the full command becomes

```
./mvnw spring-boot:run --spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/customer
```

which I imagine is what you want.

Comment: Thanks, @HansKilian for your message. I find another solution because the option with `ENTRYPOINT ...` did not work. To start the docker image I have used this command 
`docker run --name java-docker --rm -p 8080:8080 --network demo_full_stack_postgres -e SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/customer java-docker
`